# Does changing a column using Content Type affect whole site?

Tags: content-type

I was trying to remove 'Title' column from a list using content type after reading this article
http://www.endusersharepoint.com/2010/01/05/how-to-remove-the-%E2%80%9Ctitle%E2%80%9D-column-from-a-sharepoint-list/

Once I did it, 'Title' column vanished from all lists when I clicked on 'New' button?

Is there a way to restrict the content type modification restricted to a specific list only?

Anybody has an article which explains the pros & cons of Content Type usage...it does seem scary when something vanishes!!

-saumil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you seen is the expected behaviour of Content Types.

If you don't want "Title" to appear in a specific list, just remove it from that list only and not the Content Type.